# Overrided default grails constraints config not working

Tags: grails

I declared my default constraints as:

```
grails.gorm.default.constraints = {
    '*'(display: false,nullable:true,blank:true)
}
```

In one of my domain classes for example, I am adding the list of fields that I want to set constraints for and overriding the `display`, `nullable`, and `blank`. When I launch the web page it's blank and the 3 fields that I am overriding are not displayed.

What is the proper way to override the global constraints?

**EDIT: DOMAIN CLASS**

```
    class Content {
    // int id
    int parentId = 0
    int userId
    String title
    String body
    String summary
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    static mapping = {
        version false
        // autoTimestamp false
        parentId column: 'parent__id'
        userId column: 'user_id'
        //title
        //body
        //summary
        dateCreated column: 'date_created'
        lastUpdated column: 'last_updated'
    }

    static constraints = {
        title(display: true, nullable:false, blank:false, maxSize: 125)
        summary(display: true, nullable:false, blank:false)
        dateCreated(display: true, editable: false)
        lastUpdated(display: true, editable: false)
    }
}
```

**EDIT: CONTROLLER**

```
    class ContentController {
    static scaffold = true

    //def index() { }
}
```

**EDIT**

The index and create pages are blank when I set the display:false, when I remove that the form and list pages are displayed as expected. I want to set defaults that assume that we don't want to display any field and manually display the fields that I choose per domain class. I am wondering if this is a bug and that's why it's not working. I am using grails 2.4.2 in case it makes a difference.

Comment: It's good to share all the code relevant to your question. In this case, can you share your domain class? Are you using scaffolding for your controller and views?

Comment: You've fully overrided settings in the `title` and `summary` fields. And particularily  `dateCreated` and `lastUpdated`, they are will use default `nullable:true,blank:true`. If I had correctly understand your question.

Comment: @wwarlock that's right, but when I add display:false, nothing renders in my generated scaffolded views. When I remove that from the global settings, the views are rendered and the values that I overrode are overridden.